# mail app is not opening from other app if it is not configured

Tags: ios7

I am trying to share a picture via mail by calling the mail application in iPad. But when the mail is not configured it is not opening the mail application.
Kindly provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if mail is configured and alert the user to configure if not..

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
  // mail is configured
}
else
{
  //alert the user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before Displaying mail composer you should check whether device is able to sent mail or not.
If no mail configured, than display mail configuration screen/page in setting app.

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        // device can send mail, display mail composer here
    }
    else
    {
        //No mail acc is configured, so display setting for configuration 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"mailto:test@test.com"]] ;
    }
```